# Run multiple commands in single cmd with some delay

Tags: python, cmd

I want to run multiple commands in a single cmd and i want in between command to have a delay.

I have the following code

```
import os

os.system('cmd /k "command1" & "command2" & "command3"')
```

How can i add some time.sleep between these commands?

Comment: did you try `timeout <seconds>` or `pause` ?

Comment: can you not just add a windows sleep command between them?
You wouldnt be able to do this in Python as the os.system command wont give control back to python until it has finished

Comment: It would help if you explain what the commands are, because generally, one command does not run until the previous one has completed. What is the purpose of the sleep/delay? Why are you using `os.system()` instead of `subprocess.[call|popen|run]()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the Many ways of doing this, this one is perhaps the simplest:

```python3
import os

os.system('cmd /K "command1 & timeout 30 & command2 & timeout 30 & command3"')
```

This uses the `timeout` function present in the `CMD` environment, and allows the other commands to run correctly.

Note: the `CMD` option `/K` will leave garbage shell sessions on the system, instead you should use `/C` as it will cause the `CMD` instance to terminate when all of the commands are completed or an error is encountered.

ie:

```python3
import os

os.system('cmd /C "command1 & timeout 30 & command2 & timeout 30 & command3"')
```

of course you might want to control the time in seconds for each timeout:

eg:

```python3
import os
WaitSeconds1=30
WaitSeconds2=90

os.system('cmd /C "command1 & timeout '+WaitSeconds1+' & command2 & timeout '+WaitSeconds2+' & command3"')
```

All of that said, I want to be sure you understand that CMD will not execute these commands in parallel, so if the timeout is to avoid parallel processing, instead of to wait for additional things register etc.

I am aware that not every command waits to have it's work finished before exiting out (I'm looking at you, among others `DiskPart`! [Although, TBQF, Diskpart has valid reasons for being set up the way it is, it just needs to be improved for better feedback in scripting.) ).

However if you know that isn't the case, you can just use:

```python3
import os

os.system('cmd /C "command1 & command2 & command3"')
```

And, as mentioned by @Arty you can always replace the single ampersand `&` with a double ampersand `&&` in any of these examples to only have it execute the next command when the previous command completes successfully, if that is a needed conditional. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter for you to use precisely `time.sleep()`, if it matters for you just to sleep somehow then you can use built-in command `sleep <seconds>` (or `timeout <seconds>` instead of `sleep`), like in following code:

```
import os
sleep_seconds = 2
os.system(f'cmd /k "echo abc && sleep {sleep_seconds} && echo def && sleep {sleep_seconds} && echo ghi"')
```

Also probably you wanted `/c` instead of `/k`, because `/k` executes commands string and leaves cmd console running, while `/c` closes console.

---

Also you may use `subprocess.run()` + `time.sleep()`, like following:

```
import subprocess, time
sleep_seconds = 2
subprocess.run(['echo', 'abc'], check = True)
time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
subprocess.run(['echo', 'def'], check = True)
time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
subprocess.run(['echo', 'ghi'], check = True)
```

**Notice!** In the first example above you may want to use `&` instead of `&&` if needed by your task. Also in the second example set `check = False` if you want to model `&` behaviour and `check = True` if you want to model `&&` behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `time` module offered by Python.

Between the python commands to run the os commands, you can use:

```
import time
time.sleep(n)
```

where n is the number of seconds by which you want the delay to happen.